# windows 7 os won't appear

Tags: boot, grub2, windows-7

I have an asus z170m-plus motherboard with a clean install of win 7. I shrunk the win 7 partition to give space for my first ubuntu install (14.04). When I boot linux from my USB, the install option won't show the win7 os so I get the no os options and the advanced options, which I'm not familiar with as a linux novice. Any advice on how I can get the Win 7 os to show up?

I took this snapshot after extending my partition back out to see if that would fix the problem.

[image: image of file system for advanced option install]

I also tried running bootrepair after partitioning my hard drive again. Extending it didn't fix it.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/14297910/

Comment: Try selecting "advanced option" and take a screenshot of your partition scheme. Post it here. Don't worry, no changes will be done in your disk if you don't go further in the installation.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this before. Windows does not always write data in sequential order on a drive partition. When you resize the partition or create a new partition outside of Windows it is possible to delete part of the MBR or OS as it is not stored in the earlier sections of the partition. What this means is if Windows has written data to a sector is on the partition that you've shrink you will have no noot or corrupt OS. This is also part of the reason why users have trouble cloning a larger hard drive to a smaller SSD and this explains why you are not able to boot into windows anymore. The best solution is to reinstall windows and create your correct partition size then install Ubuntu in its own partition.